# Prolog return right node of binary tree

Tags: recursion, prolog, binary-tree

How do I make a method in prolog that takes a node from a binary tree and returns the right node of that node in full. 
For example if you are given node(H,R,L) I want a new node (R,R's right,R's Left)

Comment: `node_right(node(_,R,_),R).`. And why are you storing right and left trees as `node(H,R,L)` instead of `node(H,L,R)`?

Comment: oh that was just a mistake, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the node just be `R`? Then if you want to get `R`'s components, unify: `R = node(HR, RR, LR)`, or directly: `node(H, node(HR, RR, LR), L)`.